# VBS (non-webdeveloping): How to start a window hidden?

Tags: vbscript

Have a question about VBS: How can i start a new window (e.g. of firefox.exe) hidden, so it won't be shown in taskbar and you won't see the window? I know its possible but I don't know how anymore...

thanks for help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [`WshShell.Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky.aspx) method with the *intWindowStyle* parameter set to 0:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run "notepad", 0
```

Answer (score 3):

I think shell will suit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.85).aspx