# How to launch multiple applications from a sed file

Tags: sed, iexpress

I have created a .sed file for input in iexpress.exe. The entry in .sed file has two applications. One is a batch file and another is an .exe file, for example:

```
AppLaunched=cmd.exe /c abc.bat
AppLaunched2=setup.exe
```

After creating the setup and executing, only the batch file is executed. I want to execute both files.

Any idea?

Comment: do you mean Unix/Linux `sed`, as in **S**tream **ED**itor? If not, note the definition when you hover on the `sed` tag above. If you have a different meaning for sed, consider making a new tag like `sed-Windows-something_different`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly you could try using & to chain commands,

```
AppLaunched=cmd.exe /c abc.bat & setup.exe
```

There are a few other ways but this is one of the most simplistic.

Comment: this command is working fine. But I need to run the application as background process. So I tried as in .sed file the following entry ShowInstallProgramWindow=1
HideExtractAnimation=1, But this is working only for abc.bat but not working for setup.exe.

Comment: @n34_panda: you have mentioned other ways to achieve this in your answer, would you please let me know what are those ways. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could use a very simple VBScript file to run programs hidden; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4876112/422043